# Facebook credits callback detecting request

Tags: php, facebook, callback, facebook-credits

Is there a way to detect a callback request is from facebook or not as it seems like the request is not ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/callback/

You can verify that the callback is being called by Facebook by decoding the signed_request.

```
{
   "signed_request":"PfjakldsFWWs...",
   "buyer":"221159",
   "receiver":"221159",
   "order_id":"9006136047935",
   "order_info":""fbhat"",
   "method":"payments_get_items"
}
```

Comment: yeah, i can get the signed request from facebook,  But is there any way i know that the call is done by facebook and not by someone else..

Comment: yes, by decoding the signed_request and validating the contents (that's what signed means...that you can verify the contents of the message by the signature that contains encryption by public/private keys).  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/